# How to convert existing SVN path to lowercase?

Tags: svn

I have an existing SVN directory path with camel case that look like this, `IP_PATH/svn/ProjectA`. I would like to change the path to lowercase that look like this, `IP_PATH/svn/projecta`, anyhow I couldn't find any source that doing this, may I know can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the background of your question is that you are on windows and your file system can't distinguish the upper and lower case characters.

Using the `svn` command with an url is the approbate workaround:

```
svn mv -m "rename to lower case directory name" \
IP_PATH/svn/ProjectA IP_PATH/svn/projecta
```

Comment: Not sure if it's still an open issue but this used to confuse clients doing updates with case insensitive file systems.  Be good to do a real world test if it could impact others.

Comment: I assume that `svn mv` command is applied to all platform. I am worry what if the path has been change and SVN not able to trace back the path as it has been change to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue moving a folder due to case sensitivity (OSX 10.10).  I had to move the original folder to a temporary name in my working copy before moving it to it's final name.

**for example:**

```
svn mv ProjectA      ProjectA_tmp
svn mv ProjectA_tmp  projecta
svn commit -m "rename to lower case directory name"
```